# Error on MSVC++ with extending iostream

Tags: c++, logging, iostream, outputstream, extending-classes

I'm writing an output manager class for my application and although my class works on g++ under linux, it won't compile under MSVC++ 2010.

Here is a SSCCE version of my program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

template<class cT, class traits=std::char_traits<cT> >
class BasicE3OutStream: public std::basic_ostream<cT, traits> {
    public:
        BasicE3OutStream() :
                std::basic_ios<cT, traits>(), std::basic_ostream<cT, traits>(0), mBuffer() {
            resetModifiers();
            mLineBuffer=(std::stringstream*) malloc(sizeof(std::stringstream));
            mLineBuffer=new (mLineBuffer) std::stringstream();
        }

        BasicE3OutStream(const BasicE3OutStream<cT,traits> &) {
        }

        virtual ~BasicE3OutStream() {
            delete mLineBuffer;
            mLineBuffer=NULL;
        }

        void resetModifiers() {
            mDebug=false;
            mMemory=false;
        }

        void open(const char* fileName) {
            mBuffer.open(fileName, std::stringstream::out);
        }

        void close() {
            mBuffer.close();
        }

        template<class T>
        BasicE3OutStream& operator<<(T val) {
            (*mLineBuffer)<<val;
            return (*this);
        }

        BasicE3OutStream& operator<<(char* val) {
            (*mLineBuffer)<<val;
            return (*this);
        }

        BasicE3OutStream& operator<<(std::string val) {
            (*mLineBuffer)<<val;
            return (*this);
        }

        void addLineFeed() {
            std::string modifier;
            modifier="";
            if (mDebug)
                modifier+="[DEBUG] ";
            else if (mMemory)
                modifier+="[MEMORY] ";

            mBuffer<<modifier<<mLineBuffer->str()<<"\n";
            mLineBuffer->~basic_stringstream();
            mLineBuffer=new (mLineBuffer) std::stringstream();
            resetModifiers();
        }

        void flush() {
            mBuffer.flush();
            resetModifiers();
        }

        void setFlag(int f) {
            if (f==0)
                mDebug=true;
            else if (f==1)
                mMemory=true;
        }
    public:
        std::basic_ofstream<cT, traits> mBuffer;
        std::stringstream* mLineBuffer;
        bool mDebug, mMemory;
};

template<class cT, class traits, class T>
BasicE3OutStream<cT, traits>& operator<<(BasicE3OutStream<char, traits>& str , T val) {
    str.operator <<(val);
    return (str);
}

typedef BasicE3OutStream<char> E3OutStream;

template<class charT, class traits>
BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& endl(BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& os) {
    os.addLineFeed();
    return (os);
}

template<class charT, class traits>
BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& flush(BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& os) {
    os.flush();
    return (os);
}

template<class charT, class traits>
BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& debug(BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& os) {
    os.setFlag(0);
    return (os);
}

template<class charT, class traits>
BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& memory(BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& os) {
    os.setFlag(1);
    return (os);
}

/**
 * Io manipulator, allows to use endl and other modificators
 */
template<class charT, class traits> BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& operator<<(
        BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits> &s
        , BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>& (*iomanip)(BasicE3OutStream<charT, traits>&)) {
    return (iomanip(s));
}


int main() {
    E3OutStream s;
    s.open("output.txt");
    s<<debug<<"Debug info"<<endl;
    s<<flush;
    s<<memory<<"Memory info"<<endl;
    s<<flush;
    s.close();
}
```

It runs fine in g++ however on MSVC I get a compiler error :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: sscce, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(129): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(43): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(48): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(std::string)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(E3OutStream, overloaded-function)'
1>c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(130): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(43): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(48): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(std::string)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(E3OutStream, overloaded-function)'
1>c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(131): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(43): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(48): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(std::string)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(E3OutStream, overloaded-function)'
1>c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(132): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(43): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\guillaume\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sscce\sscce\main.cpp(48): or       'BasicE3OutStream<cT> &BasicE3OutStream<cT>::operator <<(std::string)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              cT=char
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(E3OutStream, overloaded-function)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Guillaume

[EDIT]

Thanks to this adviceI was given, I was able to realize that extending iostream was not useful in that case since I already had an ofstream as a member variable. Since I don't know enough of the internal working of the std library, I made my class independant and it worked on both MSVC and g++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

class BasicE3OutStream {
    public:
        BasicE3OutStream() :
                mBuffer() {
            resetModifiers();
            mLineBuffer=(std::stringstream*) malloc(sizeof(std::stringstream));
            mLineBuffer=new (mLineBuffer) std::stringstream();
        }

        BasicE3OutStream(const BasicE3OutStream &) {
        }

        virtual ~BasicE3OutStream() {
            delete mLineBuffer;
            mLineBuffer=NULL;
        }

        void resetModifiers() {
            mDebug=false;
            mMemory=false;
        }

        void open(const char* fileName) {
            mBuffer.open(fileName, std::stringstream::out);
        }

        void close() {
            mBuffer.close();
        }

        template<class T>
        BasicE3OutStream& operator<<(T val) {
            (*mLineBuffer)<<val;
            return (*this);
        }

        void addLineFeed() {
            std::string modifier;
            modifier="";
            if (mDebug)
                modifier+="[DEBUG] ";
            else if (mMemory)
                modifier+="[MEMORY] ";

            mBuffer<<modifier<<mLineBuffer->str()<<"\n";
            mLineBuffer->str("");
            resetModifiers();
        }

        void flush() {
            mBuffer.flush();
            resetModifiers();
        }

        void setFlag(int f) {
            if (f==0)
                mDebug=true;
            else if (f==1)
                mMemory=true;
        }
    public:
        std::ofstream mBuffer;
        std::stringstream* mLineBuffer;
        bool mDebug, mMemory;
};

BasicE3OutStream& endl(BasicE3OutStream& os) {
    os.addLineFeed();
    return (os);
}

BasicE3OutStream& flush(BasicE3OutStream& os) {
    os.flush();
    return (os);
}

BasicE3OutStream& debug(BasicE3OutStream& os) {
    os.setFlag(0);
    return (os);
}

BasicE3OutStream& memory(BasicE3OutStream& os) {
    os.setFlag(1);
    return (os);
}

/**
 * Io manipulator, allows to use endl and other modificators
 */
BasicE3OutStream& operator<<(
        BasicE3OutStream &s
        , BasicE3OutStream& (*iomanip)(BasicE3OutStream&)) {
    return (iomanip(s));
}


typedef BasicE3OutStream E3OutStream;

int main() {
    E3OutStream s;
    s.open("output.txt");
    s<<debug<<"Debug info"<<endl;
    s<<flush;
    s<<memory<<"Memory info"<<endl;
    s<<flush;
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can create a reduced testcase, and create an http://sscce.org from that. Please do so.

Comment: (1) I bet you used 'using std' in your code, so when you 'operator<<' flush (or some other function) it cant figure out which 'flush' you meant or which 'operator<<' it should try.  You have to say which overload of the function. (2) I think theres a better way to clear stringstreams. (3) You seem to have misunderstood inheritance.  Proof:  All of the inhereted functions dont apply to your output stream.

Comment: @Xeo Thanks for the advice, I've make my code stand-alone so that all the problem is contained in the attached source. I'll see if I can reduce the size further while maintaining the bug.

Comment: @MooingDuck (1) No I didn't use 'using std' (2) I don't really see what you mean... (3) I don't reall see anyway how you can pass a function into a stream unless there is a kind of overloaded function that takes a function pointer...

Comment: Well, it's not really reduced, is it? :) For real reduction, cut out the whole IOstreams stuff, just make a stub class and provide the overloads + methods and see if the error remains.

Comment: @GuillaumeMatheron: (2) `mLineBuffer.str("")` instead of placement new.  (3) The `open` function you're using applies to the stream you inherit from, not `mBuffer`.  If you open the file that "worked" you should find that it is empty.  Your GCC code does _not_ work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, thanks to this advice, I was able to realize that extending iostream was not useful in that case since I already had an ofstream as a member variable. Since I don't know enough of the internal working of the std library, I made my class independant and it worked on both MSVC and g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem is that you're sending function pointers to your stream, which GCC seems to know how to handle, but MSVC++ doesn't.  Either way, I doubt you wanted to save the address of the `debug`/`endl`/`flush`/`memory` functions.

The next-step resolution is to make those *objects* instead of functions that you display.

However, there's a *lot* wrong with this code.  Namely, there already exist `endl` and `flush` objects, which you should be using.  Also, each `BasicE3OutStream` has *three* underlying streams, one it inherited from, that all the functions work on, (including `endl` and such, which I assume is why you replaced them), and `mBuffer` and `mLineBuffer`, (neither of the members is needed for what you're doing).  (Another side note, reset a stringstream with `mLineBuffer.str("");`, not placement new)

The easy way to do what you want is to overload each of the `operator<<` members of a `basic_ostream`, and wherever there is a newline, insert `[DEBUG]` or `[MEMORY]` as appropreate, there's no need to buffer.  (I've done this, it's not crazy hard)

There's probably a *right* way to do this by using a stream with different char traits, or overloading certain virtual functions, or replacing the buffer, but streams are complicated, and I don't know this *right* way.